# TIC TOC not accurate enough to tell me which of these two lines of code is fastest

Tags: r, performance, dataframe

I am running this code in R, where df is a data frame :

```
x = df[df$column_one > 0, ][1,2] / df[df$column_one > 0, ][1,1]
```

I want to know if this would be faster :

```
tf = df$column_one > 0
x = df[tf, ][1,2] / df[tf > 0, ][1,1]
```

I tried using tic() toc() to get the time, but both return elapsed time : 0.00000000 seconds.

Comment: Have a look at the `microbenchmark` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running each code chunk all at once, try using:

```
t0 <- Sys.time()

x = df[df$column_one > 0, ][1,2] / df[df$column_one > 0, ][1,1]

t1 <- Sys.time() - t0

t1
```

```
t2 <- Sys.time()

tf = df$column_one > 0
x = df[tf, ][1,2] / df[tf > 0, ][1,1]

t3 <- Sys.time() - t2

t3
```

It might also be useful to run a large loop with several thousand iterations if the code executes quickly (e.g., microseconds). You can run a t-test to see if the means are significantly different.